# Condition with React

Tags: reactjs

Got a little issue with my code. I don't know what's wrong here, the only thing I know is the issue comes from the condition, but don't know where and why.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Module.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'


const Module = ({game, position}) => (
  <div className="module">
  { position ? (
    <img className="imageModule" src={`../Pictures/${game}.jpg`} alt={`Module ${game}`} />
    <div className="description"></div>
  ):(
    <div className="description"></div>
    <img className="imageModule" src={`../Pictures/${game}.jpg`} alt={`Module ${game}`} />
  )}
  </div>
)

Module.propTypes = {
  game: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  position: PropTypes.number.isRequired
}

export default Module
```

Syntax error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>? (10:5)

Comment: Just wrap the components inside your brackets in [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) (`<> ... </>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jsx, you can't write an expressione like this:

```
(
    <img className="imageModule" src={`../Pictures/${game}.jpg`} alt={`Module 
${game}`} />
    <div className="description"></div>
  )
```

because these are two elements. You must wrap in a `<div>` tag or wrap it between `Fragment` or `<></>`

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your element with <>.

```
const Module = ({game, position}) => (
  <div className="module">
  { position ? (
    <>
    <img className="imageModule" src={`../Pictures/${game}.jpg`} alt={`Module ${game}`} />
    <div className="description"></div>
   </>
  ):(
   <>
    <div className="description"></div>
    <img className="imageModule" src={`../Pictures/${game}.jpg`} alt={`Module ${game}`} />
  </>
  )}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the HTML in the condition into <> </> tag, like this:

```
{ position ? (
    <>
    <img className="imageModule" src={`../Pictures/${game}.jpg`} alt={`Module ${game}`} />
    <div className="description"></div>
    </>
  ):(
    <>
    <div className="description"></div>
    <img className="imageModule" src={`../Pictures/${game}.jpg`} alt={`Module ${game}`} />
    </>  
)}
```